Is it possible to add a data attribute to a select option using the .add method
I am trying to find the correct syntax to add a data attribute to an HTML select option.
I have a lot pre-existing code that uses the following method to add options to a select:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="ordertype" id="ordertype"></select>
</body>
    <script>
        var thisElement = document.getElementById('ordertype');
        var optionNew;
        optionNew = document.createElement("option");
        optionNew.text = "test text;
        optionNew.value = "0";
        thisElement.add(optionNew, null);
    </script>
</html>

https://jsfiddle.net/2g67pkxr/
This result is:
<select name="ordertype" id="ordertype">
    <option value="0">test text</option>
</select>

I would like to adda data attribute to produce the following:
<select name="ordertype" id="ordertype">
    <option data-mytest="a1234" value="0">test text</option>
</select>

Is this possible using my existing method?
